# How to make player-sprite "jump" using SpriteKits built-in physics engine

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-physics

I'm a little confused trying to find a reliable way to make my player-sprite jump when the user taps the screen.

So far I've been doing this:

```
if(self.physicsBody.velocity.dy == 0.0 && _shouldJump) {
  [self.physicsBody applyImpulse: CGVectorMake(0.0, 195.0);
}
```

Which works, but I'm looking for something more reliable and better. Specifically, right now, the user cannot jump when he's sliding down a slope, or on the edge of a block about to fall down (because `.dy` isn't exactly 0). I'd like the player to be able to jump in these cases too.

I've tried something like `.dy < 5.0 && .dy > -5.0`, but then he's able to jump when he's at the top of his current jump, making him jump even higher.

Is there a way of checking which `physicsBodies` my player-sprite is in contact with maybe? Or do you have any other suggestions?

I have read *Ray Wenderlich's* tutorial on how to create a **Platform Game Like Super Mario**, but they're building their own custom Physics Engine. I'd like to stick with the one built into SpriteKit, mainly becuase of the collision handling and detection.

**EDIT 1:**

Bear in mind that I cannot set a flag `_isOnGround = YES` every time the Player touches the ground in `didBeginContact`, as he is bouncy and will bounce up-and-down a few times before coming to a stop. I'd prefer the user to be able to jump as soon as he touches the ground when he's holding the screen, but this is not necessary.

Comment: Hmm... proper physics for a platform game is not always the best way. Mario (and other platform games) actually avoid using physics for their jumping mechanics. Mainly because it makes the game a lot harder to play. Mario games (for instance) let you "float" in the top part of the jump a lot longer than physics would allow so that it makes it easier to stick a pixel perfect landing. etc...

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm actually considering building my own physics engine, but it seems like a lot of work to scrap what I have now and start over, so I'm just trying to see if there's a way I can get away with keeping what I have. 

I don't know if you have checked out the tutorial I mentioned in my post, but if you have, do you know how I could implement angled floors (a slope) and a generally better collision detection than what's there? Any tutorials you'd recommend? Maybe use SpriteKit for collision detection, and then build my own physics handling on top of that?

Comment: Yeah, I had a read of the RW tutorial. I think the key is not to think of a physics engine. What you need is to just move things manually. Definitely use SpriteKit for collision detection. You can create physics bodies from paths too (for complex shapes). Having said that, you don't need to. Games don't need to be real, they need to be fast, responsive and fun. For the slopes... It's just another type of floor. You can detect the contact type and change your movement speed and animation set depending on the slope etc...

Comment: @Fogmeister I don't think I understand what you mean (I don't have much experience with game development). Right now, I don't do anything special for the slopes. Everything is built using 32x32 blocks, and for the slopes I just create a `physicsbody` out of a custom triangular shape that follows the image. The rest is handled by SpriteKit, and it kinda just works. How would I go about making this work when I position the sprites manually? And another thing: When moving the Sprites, I experience some sort of lag even though it's running at around 60fps. Do you know if going custom will help?